# I need to do a css task without editing index.html or normalize.css

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
html,
body {
  background-color: lightgray
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 780px;
  background-color: rgb(84, 153, 199);
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 780px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.photo {
  height: 160px;
}

h1,
.help {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 18px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.figure {
  border-bottom: solid #BBBBBB;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-left: 214px;
  width: 340px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 160px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #BBBBBB;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}

p {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

div.help {
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 800px;
  margin-top: -1000px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.photo-grid {
  width: 228px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Layout i HTML</h1>
    </div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam lobortis commodo purus, et imperdiet sapien varius vel. Aliquam quis massa at neque fringilla pharetra eu at ante. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Interdum
      et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam a orci mattis, efficitur arcu ac, porta dolor. Aenean massa metus, dictum ut nibh ut, porttitor gravida tellus. Maecenas ex velit, pharetra quis pulvinar quis, rhoncus et augue. Donec sit
      amet ex elit. Sed at nibh in lorem porttitor eleifend id ac justo. Aliquam eget libero facilisis, faucibus libero nec, ornare elit. Nunc accumsan libero vitae justo hendrerit, sed facilisis velit efficitur. Nullam aliquet dolor nibh, vel fringilla
      tortor facilisis ut. Curabitur ultrices dapibus purus. Nullam porttitor odio a malesuada accumsan. Duis eget diam metus. Suspendisse potenti.</p>

    <div class="right photo">
      <img src="img/photo-one.png">
      <img src="img/photo-two.png">
    </div>

    <p>Vestibulum cursus tellus id pulvinar pellentesque. Suspendisse euismod augue sit amet lorem tempus, vitae ornare quam auctor. Sed placerat eleifend nunc, at semper metus hendrerit ut. Suspendisse nulla libero, suscipit quis euismod quis, sagittis
      non lectus. Integer convallis quam suscipit, lacinia felis at, molestie quam. Duis sagittis facilisis erat eget semper. Maecenas a odio enim. Morbi at odio egestas, pharetra est eu, tristique mi. Sed sed facilisis sapien, nec molestie nisl. Curabitur
      faucibus risus viverra metus ultricies, vitae bibendum sem cursus. Maecenas quis nulla sollicitudin, luctus ex efficitur, fringilla sem.</p>

    <p>Nunc rhoncus dolor vel nisi posuere imperdiet. Phasellus auctor turpis in vestibulum sodales. Vestibulum vitae nibh turpis. Sed vel vestibulum ex. Pellentesque ex lacus, venenatis a condimentum nec, venenatis id risus. Nullam mattis blandit tellus
      quis dignissim. In ultrices lacinia interdum. Maecenas quam metus, egestas eu augue aliquam, mollis elementum lorem. Sed vel nulla consequat, porta eros non, porttitor enim. Praesent id turpis in ipsum pulvinar ornare. In tincidunt sit amet nulla
      sed euismod. Sed scelerisque arcu justo, ac fringilla magna mollis vel. Phasellus ultricies sed ligula ac fringilla. Vestibulum venenatis velit non dui feugiat faucibus. Duis ut ante malesuada, egestas eros non, hendrerit sem. Fusce vehicula ante
      at maximus consectetur.</p>

    <div class="figure">
      <div>
        <img src="img/photo-three.png">
        <p>Figur 1: Duis placerat quam at lacus facilisis, a semper dolor aliquet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>Aenean ut nisl convallis, volutpat ex vulputate, varius eros. Curabitur urna quam, euismod et egestas vel, dictum vel erat. Quisque dictum quis ex id auctor. Mauris efficitur libero neque, id pulvinar odio facilisis sit amet. Fusce eleifend sem eget
      ipsum luctus pharetra. Sed efficitur non enim in blandit. Sed lacus quam, molestie nec volutpat quis, tincidunt et eros. Suspendisse id magna dictum, semper metus ac, ultricies nisi. Sed quis euismod nibh, non pulvinar turpis. Curabitur vulputate
      massa luctus varius auctor. Aenean rutrum vitae arcu quis placerat. Donec sagittis porta purus, sed posuere lorem imperdiet quis.</p>

    <div class="left photo"><img src="img/photo-four.png"></div>

    <div class="right photo-grid">
      <img src="img/photo-five.png">
      <img src="img/photo-six.png">
      <img src="img/photo-seven.png">
      <img src="img/photo-eight.png">
    </div>

    <p>Suspendisse vel consequat risus. Phasellus et posuere orci. Suspendisse iaculis pellentesque neque quis luctus. Vestibulum eget sagittis lorem. Vivamus finibus risus venenatis, gravida diam blandit, tristique eros. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
      ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque non congue eros. Quisque venenatis blandit enim, quis elementum dolor iaculis at. Mauris ut magna magna. Nulla facilisi.</p>

    <p>Fusce lacinia mauris nec nunc malesuada sollicitudin. Maecenas non enim purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ornare auctor nunc, et commodo elit condimentum ac. Mauris feugiat feugiat tortor ut egestas. Sed pellentesque
      dictum nulla sit amet euismod. Fusce lacinia pulvinar fringilla. Duis eget ante blandit, tristique sapien nec, convallis dolor. Morbi elementum ornare neque non faucibus. Quisque aliquet nisl vitae risus euismod, vitae pretium justo porta. Suspendisse
      vel tellus dictum, egestas nisl accumsan, scelerisque tellus. Nunc et faucibus mauris. Duis varius magna erat, a ullamcorper magna ullamcorper et.</p>

    <div class="help">
      <p>?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So I have these as `main.css` and `index.html`, it should look like the linked picture but instead it looks like the gyazo, the things I need to do are, border around the 2 pictures on the right, correct the orange figure and fix the questionmark help button.

[Image of how its supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra6uH.png)

[Image of how it currently looks](https://gyazo.com/fae7286aa3ad1d5180788e72436ba4a4)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the CSS class to `main.css` and the desired output is achieved.

```
.help p{
    margin:0px;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

html, body {
  background-color: lightgray
}

.header{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 780px;
background-color: rgb(84, 153, 199);
padding: 40px 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 780px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.photo{
  height: 160px;
}

h1, .help {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 18px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.figure {
  border-bottom: solid #BBBBBB;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-left: 214px;
  width: 340px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 160px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #BBBBBB;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}

p {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

div.help {
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 800px;
  margin-top: -1000px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.photo-grid {
width: 228px;
}

.help p{
margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Layout i HTML</h1>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam lobortis commodo purus, et imperdiet sapien varius vel. Aliquam quis massa at neque fringilla pharetra eu at ante. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam a orci mattis, efficitur arcu ac, porta dolor. Aenean massa metus, dictum ut nibh ut, porttitor gravida tellus. Maecenas ex velit, pharetra quis pulvinar quis, rhoncus et augue. Donec sit amet ex elit. Sed at nibh in lorem porttitor eleifend id ac justo. Aliquam eget libero facilisis, faucibus libero nec, ornare elit. Nunc accumsan libero vitae justo hendrerit, sed facilisis velit efficitur. Nullam aliquet dolor nibh, vel fringilla tortor facilisis ut. Curabitur ultrices dapibus purus. Nullam porttitor odio a malesuada accumsan. Duis eget diam metus. Suspendisse potenti.</p>

  <div class="right photo">
    <img src="img/photo-one.png">
    <img src="img/photo-two.png">
  </div>

  <p>Vestibulum cursus tellus id pulvinar pellentesque. Suspendisse euismod augue sit amet lorem tempus, vitae ornare quam auctor. Sed placerat eleifend nunc, at semper metus hendrerit ut. Suspendisse nulla libero, suscipit quis euismod quis, sagittis non lectus. Integer convallis quam suscipit, lacinia felis at, molestie quam. Duis sagittis facilisis erat eget semper. Maecenas a odio enim. Morbi at odio egestas, pharetra est eu, tristique mi. Sed sed facilisis sapien, nec molestie nisl. Curabitur faucibus risus viverra metus ultricies, vitae bibendum sem cursus. Maecenas quis nulla sollicitudin, luctus ex efficitur, fringilla sem.</p>

  <p>Nunc rhoncus dolor vel nisi posuere imperdiet. Phasellus auctor turpis in vestibulum sodales. Vestibulum vitae nibh turpis. Sed vel vestibulum ex. Pellentesque ex lacus, venenatis a condimentum nec, venenatis id risus. Nullam mattis blandit tellus quis dignissim. In ultrices lacinia interdum. Maecenas quam metus, egestas eu augue aliquam, mollis elementum lorem. Sed vel nulla consequat, porta eros non, porttitor enim. Praesent id turpis in ipsum pulvinar ornare. In tincidunt sit amet nulla sed euismod. Sed scelerisque arcu justo, ac fringilla magna mollis vel. Phasellus ultricies sed ligula ac fringilla. Vestibulum venenatis velit non dui feugiat faucibus. Duis ut ante malesuada, egestas eros non, hendrerit sem. Fusce vehicula ante at maximus consectetur.</p>

  <div class="figure">
    <div>
      <img src="img/photo-three.png">
      <p>Figur 1: Duis placerat quam at lacus facilisis, a semper dolor aliquet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>Aenean ut nisl convallis, volutpat ex vulputate, varius eros. Curabitur urna quam, euismod et egestas vel, dictum vel erat. Quisque dictum quis ex id auctor. Mauris efficitur libero neque, id pulvinar odio facilisis sit amet. Fusce eleifend sem eget ipsum luctus pharetra. Sed efficitur non enim in blandit. Sed lacus quam, molestie nec volutpat quis, tincidunt et eros. Suspendisse id magna dictum, semper metus ac, ultricies nisi. Sed quis euismod nibh, non pulvinar turpis. Curabitur vulputate massa luctus varius auctor. Aenean rutrum vitae arcu quis placerat. Donec sagittis porta purus, sed posuere lorem imperdiet quis.</p>

  <div class="left photo"><img src="img/photo-four.png"></div>

  <div class="right photo-grid">
    <img src="img/photo-five.png">
    <img src="img/photo-six.png">
    <img src="img/photo-seven.png">
    <img src="img/photo-eight.png">
  </div>

  <p>Suspendisse vel consequat risus. Phasellus et posuere orci. Suspendisse iaculis pellentesque neque quis luctus. Vestibulum eget sagittis lorem. Vivamus finibus risus venenatis, gravida diam blandit, tristique eros. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque non congue eros. Quisque venenatis blandit enim, quis elementum dolor iaculis at. Mauris ut magna magna. Nulla facilisi.</p>

  <p>Fusce lacinia mauris nec nunc malesuada sollicitudin. Maecenas non enim purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ornare auctor nunc, et commodo elit condimentum ac. Mauris feugiat feugiat tortor ut egestas. Sed pellentesque dictum nulla sit amet euismod. Fusce lacinia pulvinar fringilla. Duis eget ante blandit, tristique sapien nec, convallis dolor. Morbi elementum ornare neque non faucibus. Quisque aliquet nisl vitae risus euismod, vitae pretium justo porta. Suspendisse vel tellus dictum, egestas nisl accumsan, scelerisque tellus. Nunc et faucibus mauris. Duis varius magna erat, a ullamcorper magna ullamcorper et.</p>

  <div class="help">
    <p>?</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```